# C# and PInvoke Winapi program hangs

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, .net-5

So I'm trying to make a winapi application by using PInvoke. So far I've been able to open a window, but from there, I can't seem to make the `WndProc` work. Right now, the application starts, but it won't respond neither to resize, nor to movement or anything, except the hovering above the control buttons.

WindowLL.cs:

```cs
public delegate long WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint message, byte wParam, long lParam);
public static unsafe class WindowLL
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern ushort RegisterClassExA(ref WNDCLASSEX _class);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowExA(
        uint extraStyle,
        ushort className,
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        //string className,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string title,
        uint style,
        int x,
        int y,
        int width,
        int height,
        IntPtr parent,
        IntPtr menu,
        IntPtr instance,
        IntPtr parameter
    );
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetMessage(
        out MSG lpMsg,
        IntPtr hWnd,
        uint wMsgFilterMin,
        uint wMsgFilterMax
    );
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern uint DispatchMessage(ref MSG lpMsg);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern uint TranslateMessage(ref MSG lpMsg);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern long DefWindowProcA(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        uint Msg,
        byte wParam,
        long lParam
    );
}
```

Structures (split into different files):

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MSG
{
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public uint message;
    public byte wParam;
    public long lParam;
    public short time;
    public POINT pt;
    public short lPrivate;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public long X;
    public long Y;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WNDCLASSEX
{
    public uint      cbSize;
    public uint      style;
    public WndProc   lpfnWndProc;
    public int       cbClsExtra;
    public int       cbWndExtra;
    public IntPtr    hInstance;
    public IntPtr    hIcon;
    public IntPtr    hCursor;
    public IntPtr    hbrBackground;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string    lpszMenuName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string    lpszClassName;
    public IntPtr    hIconSm;
}
```

Program.cs:

```cs
class Program
{
    static long WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint message, byte wParam, long lParam)
    {
        return WindowLL.DefWindowProcA(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var winCalss = new WNDCLASSEX() {
            lpszClassName = "test",
            lpfnWndProc = WndProc,
            cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WNDCLASSEX)),
        };
        var classId = WindowLL.RegisterClassExA(ref winCalss);

        var overlapped =
            WindowStyle.Overlapped |
            WindowStyle.Caption |
            WindowStyle.SysMenu |
            WindowStyle.ThickFrame |
            WindowStyle.MinimizeBox |
            WindowStyle.MaximizeBox;

        IntPtr hWnd = WindowLL.CreateWindowExA(0,
            classId, "test",
            (uint)overlapped,
            0, 0,
            1280, 720,
            IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero
        );

        WindowLL.ShowWindow(hWnd, (int)NCmdShow.Show);

        while (WindowLL.GetMessage(out var msg, hWnd, 0, 0)) {
            WindowLL.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
            WindowLL.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*trying to make a winapi application by using PInvoke*" Just curious, why? The Win32 API is bare-metal, but tortuous and full of quirks. C# is easier and safer, but sandboxed. Combining the two is like cherry-picking the worst of both worlds.

Comment: @dxiv I just want to make a wrapper, like WinForms, since I find it an utter mess. I am also fully aware what I am putting up with voluntarily :). Probably it would been a great idea if I did it in C++ and then used the C++ library in C#, but I don't feel comfortable with C nor C++

Comment: This is much easier with [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp) which allows you to export a managed interface from a native implementation seamlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structures are mostly wrong.

wParam / lParam should both be IntPtr, time should be uint, point x/y should be int.

You don't even need to write them yourself, copy-paste from the framework, MIT license allow that:

https://source.dot.net/#WindowsBase/System/Windows/Interop/MSG.cs,8a0b462145bdb8d8

https://source.dot.net/#PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Standard/NativeMethods.cs,527982c752231945

One more thing. You should not be using A-functions and structures like `CreateWindowExA`. These are compatibility shims for Windows 95, 98 and Me, all 3 discontinued decades ago. Modern software should only use W-versions. As a nice side effect strings marshalling is way cheaper, C# strings are stored as UTF-16 which matches the encoding expected by W WinApi functions.

Comment: I've done everything you told me and still the application is in this "zombified" state. the cursor is the busy one and I can't move nor resize the window. Also I'm not getting the WM_CLOSE message

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to fix the `WndProc` and `DefWindowProcW` signatures. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Alternatively use [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) and never get your P/Invoke signatures and types wrong again.

Comment: @TopchetoEU Couple more things. `WndProc` and `DefWindowProcW` should return `IntPtr` not `long`, the `long` type in C# is 64-bit even for 32-bit processes. Unlike classes, C# structures already have `LayoutKind.Sequential` by default. When you pass a structure to C function like `ref WNDCLASSEX _class`, it’s slightly more efficient to apply `[In]` attribute to that argument, the runtime then won’t bother propagating possible changes made by C code back into C# structure. The WinApi specifies the argument as `const WNDCLASSEXW *`, note the `const`.